# Como duplicar esta função jQuery

Tags: jquery

Como podem estar vendo [nesse fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d6yp3b92/) de exemplo, quando o primeiro link é clicado uma div aparece e ao pressionar o botão de voltar do navegador, ela fecha.
Gostaria que o segundo link funcionasse da mesma maneira, mostrando a div dois, mas quando tento duplicar a função um dos dois param de funcionar e eu não faço ideia do porquê (sou leigo em JS/Jq).
Podem me ajudar?

Link do fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d6yp3b92/

Código:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('click touch', '#paginaUm', function(e) {
    $('.pagina.um').fadeIn();
  });
});

// geri butonunu yakalama
window.onhashchange = function(e) {
  var oldURL = e.oldURL.split('#')[1];
  var newURL = e.newURL.split('#')[1];

  if (oldURL == 'paginaUm') {
    $('.pagina.um').fadeOut();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  //console.log('old:'+oldURL+' new:'+newURL);
}
```

```css
.pagina{position:fixed; display:none; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; background:gray; color:white; padding:20px;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#paginaUm" id="paginaUm">Pagina 1</a>
  <div class="pagina um">
  <h1>Popup 1</h1>
  <p>Pressione voltar para fechar.</p>
</div>

<a href="#paginaDois" id="paginaDois">Pagina 2</a>
  <div class="pagina dois">
  <h1>Popup 2</h1>
  <p>Pressione voltar para fechar.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Se cada `<a>` abre o `<div>` que está lá dentro então você fazer tudo com um evento de click se alterar um pouco as classes que tem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não sei dizer exatamente se essa é a melhor prática, mas se vc fizr um evento de click para cada btn vc consegue duplicar o código de boa

Veja o exemplo, teste no seu ambiente clicando no btn voltar que vai funcionar direitinho, ou aqui mesmo, ou nesse link https://codepen.io/hugocsl/pen/oJXpWW

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#paginaUm").click(function(event){
    $('.pagina.um').fadeIn();
  });
  $("#paginaDois").click(function(event){
    $('.pagina.dois').fadeIn();
  });
});

// geri butonunu yakalama
window.onhashchange = function(e) {
  var oldURL = e.oldURL.split('#')[1];
  var newURL = e.newURL.split('#')[1];

  if (oldURL == 'paginaUm') {
    $('.pagina.um').fadeOut();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
   if (oldURL == 'paginaDois') {
    $('.pagina.dois').fadeOut();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }

  //console.log('old:'+oldURL+' new:'+newURL);
}
```

```css
.pagina{position:fixed; display:none; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; background:gray; color:white; padding:20px;
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<a href="#paginaUm" id="paginaUm">Pagina 1</a>
  <div class="pagina um">
  <h1>Popup 1</h1>
  <p>Pressione voltar para fechar.</p>
</div>

<a href="#paginaDois" id="paginaDois">Pagina 2</a>
  <div class="pagina dois">
  <h1>Popup 2</h1>
  <p>Pressione voltar para fechar.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Tá ótimo! Agradeço bastante!

Comment: @ThiagoSoubra valeu jovem, do jeito que fiz tenho certeza que funciona, mas é que tem uns caras aqui no site muito fera mesmo, que as vezes resolvem esses problemas com 2 linhas de código rss. Mas esse jeito ai fica de fácil entendimento pra quem é mais leigo tipo a gente :D

Comment: Verdade mesmo! Cada vez mais entendemos da linguagem mais conseguimos reduzir os códigos, mas o que importa é que funciona! rsrs

Comment: vc sabe como fazer para usar esse sistema também por meio de um botão? porque além do popup ser fechado pelo botão de voltar, também há um botão que permite fechá-lo. Percebi que a coisa buga se eu simplesmente acionar a função de ocultar aquela div ao botão. Vi que o #link não sai do url, dai quando clico para abrir novamente (ou outro popup com o mesmo método), ele não abre, meio que precisa que o url esteja "limpo"... então eu acho que é preciso que seja possível realizar o mesmo processo que 'voltar' ao clicar nesse botão de fechar. Se não souber, posso abrir uma nova pergunta!

Comment: @ThiagoSoubra faz o seguinte, primeiro vc tem que coloca a classe `.fechar`, no seu caso é na tag `<p>` que tem o texto "Pressione para fechar". Depois disso lá dentro do script vc inclui isso `$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".fechar").click(function (event) {
                $('[class^="pagina"]').fadeOut();
                document.location.href = String( document.location.href ).replace( /#paginaUm/, "" ) ;
                document.location.href = String( document.location.href ).replace( /#paginaDois/, "" );
            });
        }); ` testa ai que deve funcionar

Comment: amigo, dá certo, mas recarrega a página quando clicado :| seria possível fazer que não recarregasse?

Comment: @ThiagoSoubra aqui não está fazendo o refresh, atualizei o link, veja https://codepen.io/hugocsl/pen/oJXpWW qq coisa me fala

Comment: estranho, aqui atualiza. olha, gravei a tela nesse curto vídeo: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18OEMVRRC8sDko-0nj4HW-IRQmERNxfv1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: coloquei uma imagem na pagina pra ela ficar mais "pesada" e dá pra ver melhor o reload

Comment: @ThiagoSoubra é Jovem acho que não consegui dessa vez. Fiz uns testes aqui, atualizei novamente o link inclusive. E esse código é instavel, tem horas que até apaga a navbar no topo não sei pq. Vc pode desmarcar a resposta como aceita que não tem problema. Mas de qq forma te indico abrir outra pergunta, para alguém com mais conhecimento te ajudar nessa parte da URL.

Comment: Essa cê respondeu, já foi suficiente. Essa outra dúvida foi a parte... vou abrir outra. Mas obrigadão por tudo!!!!